# Exporting render of polygon after applying smooth geometry command using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, smoothing

I have recently discovered the smooth($geometry,x) command in QGIS which is very convenient for me. However, when exporting polygons, the "smoothness" obviously goes away as the vertices are untouched by the command. (the command is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEurXCS1hEw )

Is there a way for me to extract the rendering of the polygon **as it shows** after applying the command?

The goal being to be able to load the polygon later on in other projects without having to reuse the command, and with vertices that match the render I had previously achieved.

I'm attaching a picture to help explain what I'm looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open "Geometry by expression" from your processing toolbox, choose your desired output type (polygon) and enter your expression.

[image]